# How to gain access to office web app through windows live

Tags: office-365, office-online

I just signed up for a windows live account and according to microsoft: http://windowslivehelp.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=1a5ba36b-f9ea-412b-bc44-bd5bfada3084

I should have access to their office web apps eventhough i dont have office 2010 installed in my machine.

Strangely I cant create office documents using my windows live account.

Is there any specific settings in my profile to enable this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some regions, Office Web Apps is not enabled, but you still can enable it if you go to http://office.live.com/?docsf=1. It could not be in your language tough.

Comment: Thanks this is actually what happened in my account =) I use a different country in my use profile as a work around

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your SkyDrive account ([skydrive.live.com](http://skydrive.live.com))
2. Click the "New" item on the upper-left corner
3. Select the type of document you want to create (see image)
4. Alternatively, upload an existing Office 2007/2010 document, select it and choose "Edit in browser"

In both cases, the document will open in an online Office app.

[image]